# Remap ¤ and $ on norwegian keyboard Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, 17.10

How to swap the keys for ¤ and $ on a norwegian keyboard?

¤ = shift + 4

$ = Alt Gr + 4

I want it to be

$ = Shift + 4

¤ = Alt Gr + 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the `latin` symbols file.

```
--- /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/latin.orig
+++ /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/latin
@@ -62,15 +62,15 @@
 xkb_symbols "type2" {

     include "latin"

     key <AE01> { [         1,     exclam,   exclamdown,  onesuperior ] };
     key <AE02> { [         2,   quotedbl,           at,  twosuperior ] };
     key <AE03> { [         3, numbersign,     sterling, threesuperior] };
-    key <AE04> { [         4,   currency,       dollar,   onequarter ] };
+    key <AE04> { [         4,     dollar,     currency,   onequarter ] };
     key <AE05> { [         5,    percent,      onehalf,         cent ] };
     key <AE06> { [         6,  ampersand,          yen,  fiveeighths ] };
     key <AE07> { [         7,      slash,    braceleft,     division ] };
     key <AE08> { [         8,  parenleft,  bracketleft, guillemotleft] };
     key <AE09> { [         9, parenright, bracketright, guillemotright] };
     key <AE10> { [         0,      equal,   braceright,       degree ] };
```